# Should I use MongoDB arrays or nested documents?

Tags: mongodb, dictionary

I would like to store a nested dictionary structure in a MongoDB database. However, I am not sure if I should use MongoDB arrays or nested documents:

**Option 1 (arrays):**

```
devices (collection)
    - name [str]
    - components [array]
        [
        - name [str]
        - type [str]
        ]
```

**Option2 (nested documents):**

```
devices (collection)
    - name [str]
    - components [document]
        - component1_name [document]
            - type [str]
        - component2_name [document]
            - type [str]
```

(Note that there will be more fields, this is just a minimal example. Typically, the number of *components* vary across *devices*.)

I feel like Option 1 is more flexible as the document structure (names of the fields) is fixed (field names will vary across *devices* in Option 2).
However, if I want to query the *type* of a specific *component* (like finding `devices[0]['components']['component1_name']['type']` in a dictionary), Option 2 looks better.

(Note: Maybe I shouldn't use MongoDB at all and stick with plain dictionaries? The idea of MongoDB was to later perform aggregation queries and use data visualization tools.)

Thanks!

Comment: Although option/opinion questions are frowned upon on SO, in general Option 1 is better because it follows the rule of "no rvals as lvals" i.e. "no values in a domain as keys."    To find a particular component in Option 1 you would use `$filter` on the array.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I thought this question would fall under the "coding techniques" category, but I'll try not to put explicit options next time...